# Does $f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ(g \circ f)$ imply $f = g$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

If f and g are functions such that $f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ(g \circ f)$, then $f = g$.

I am really confuse at this question and unable to identify if the function is true or false. Can anyone please show me how to prove this statement or disprove by providing counterexample? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just take two different functions $f,g$, which commute, i.e., with $f\circ g=g\cdot f$.
An example would be $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is true so that I don't need provide counterexample because it is for only when function is not true. My logic is since both functions have same f o can be cancelled. And f(g(x)) , g(f(x)) so that f = g

Comment: @hpotter054: If there exists a counterexample, *just one*, then the claim *cannot* be true. No amount of arguing can go around that simple fact. Just think of a real-world example of the same argumentation type: **You:** "Are all ravens black?" **Other:** "No, look at that raven over there, it's white." **You:** "But I believe all ravens are black because it's in their genes. So I don't need a counterexample."

Comment: @hpotter054: Also, you're wrong twice in your argumentation: In general $f\circ$ cannot be cancelled (see my answer for a counterexample), and from $f(g(x)=g(f(x))$ it doesn't follow that $f=g$ (the counterexample is right in the answer above).

Answer (score 1):

Another counter example are projectors (i.e. $p\circ p=p$)

For instance in $\mathbb R^3$ let's have $f=P_{xy}$ and $g=P_{yz}$, respectively the projectors on the plane XY and on the plane YZ.

Then $\begin{cases}
f\circ g\circ f(x,y,z)=f\circ g(x,y,0)=f(0,y,0)=(0,y,0)\\
f\circ f\circ g(x,y,z)=f\circ f(0,y,z)=f(0,y,0)=(0,y,0)\\
\end{cases}$

So $f\circ g\circ f=f\circ f\circ g$ but $f\neq g$.

---

But it is possible to find counter examples even when $f$ and $g$ do not commute.

This requires $f$ to take the same values $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a\neq b$ with $a=f(g(x))$ and $b=g(f(x))$

- Let's start with a basic example

$\begin{cases}
f(0)=f(1)=1,\ f(x)=??\ \text{elsewhere}\\
g(x)=0\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}a=f(g(x))=f(0)=1 \\b=g(f(x))=0\end{cases}\quad$

yet $f(a)=f(b)=1$.

- Or let's take $f$ even and $g$ always negative and even.

$\begin{cases}
f(x)=|x|\\
g(x)=-e^{x^2}\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}a=f(g(x))=e^{x^2}\\b=g(f(x))=-e^{x^2}\end{cases}\quad$

yet $f(a)=f(b)=e^{x^2}$.

- We could also take $f$ periodic and $g$ a translation.

$\begin{cases}
f(x)=\sin(x)\\
g(x)=2\pi+x\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}a=f(g(x))=\sin(2\pi+x)=\sin(x)\\b=g(f(x))=2\pi+\sin(x)\end{cases}\quad$

yet $f(a)=f(b)=\sin(\sin(x))$.

- You can even combine the two above.

$\begin{cases}
f(x)=\sin(x)\\
g(x)=\pi+x\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}a=f(g(x))=\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin(x)\\b=g(f(x))=\pi+\sin(x)\end{cases}\quad$

$f(a)=\sin(-\sin(x))=-\sin(\sin(x))$

$f(b)=\sin(\pi+\sin(x))=-\sin(\sin(x))=f(a)$.

It's up to your imagination to find counter examples...

Comment: I am pretty sure this is true so that I don't need provide counterexample because it is for only when function is not true. My logic is since both functions have same f o can be cancelled. And f(g(x)) , g(f(x)) so that f = g.

Answer (score 0):

Be $f$ a constant function. Then for *any* function $h$, you have $f\circ h=f$. This is in particular true for both $h=f\circ g$ and $h=g\circ f$, no matter what $g$ is. In particular, it also holds for $g\ne f$.